# How to see cyrillic symbols in PostgreSQL errors?

Tags: postgresql, encoding

I have a PostgreSQL on Windows 7 machine. And here my data base script:

```
CREATE DATABASE usersdb
   WITH OWNER = postgres
   ENCODING = 'UTF8'
   TABLESPACE = pg_default
   LC_COLLATE = 'Russian_Russia.1251'
   LC_CTYPE = 'Russian_Russia.1251'
   CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

My problem in that i see unreadable error in Jetty/Tomcat:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ?????: ???????????? "test_user" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)
```

I try create new db in pgAdmin but there are only  LC_COLLATE = 'Russian_Russia.1251' and LC_CTYPE = 'Russian_Russia.1251' i can chose.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Fiddle with [`LC_MESSAGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/locale.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look, of course, are in the PostgreSQL logs.  Those may be better handled than your Jetty/Tomcat instance.

The second question is what client encoding is set.  You may want to (via jdbc):

```
show client_encoding;
```

Finally lc_messages may need to be adjusted.